# How much does the Logitech G930 headset actually weigh?

Tags: wireless-headset, logitech-headset

I'm considering buying the G930 headset and I'm trying to find out how heavy that thing actually is. Should be easy to find out, but apparently isn't...

I realize this is kind of a trivia question, but after clicking through dozens of review sites and spec sheets without getting a definitive answer, I figured I might as well ask here.

Logitech doesn't have the weight on the product homepage, and the few reviews that did include numbers don't agree on the weight. The numbers I found are 8.7 ounces (~250g), "more than 300g", 420g, and finally 2.2 pounds (that's the shipping weight, I suppose).

Maybe someone (a G930 owner perhaps) can give a definite answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11.7 oz according to this page    using search words "logitech G930 weight oz"

http://dealnay.com/1062552/logitech-g930-wireless-gaming-headset.html

.

and this one

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Logitech+-+G930+Wireless+Gaming+Headset/1388362.p?id=1218255234461&skuId=1388362